# MS Access 2003: Do multiple identical entries in .ldb indicate errors?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

Does it indicate an error if the same user (on the same computer) appears multiple time in the .ldb file, or does this merely reports that the same user has opened the DB several times?

Example .ldb:

```
Admin
    computer1
Admin
    computer2
Admin
    computer1
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not an error. It indicates that the user on `computer1` has opened the database twice (two instances of Access are running).

Note that if you don't use the `/User` parameter when starting Access, the user name as reported by `CurrentUser()` is always `Admin`

Also worth noting: the .ldb file is not updated, if he closes one instance, only when he closes the last instance on his computer.